# Serialize value to OData

Tags: .net, odata, odatalib

Is there a function (perhaps in ODataLib 5.6.1) to serialize a .NET primitive type to OData URI format ([see](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem))

for instance:

```
new DateTime(2000,12,12).ToODataString() //would return: datetime’2000-12-12T12:00′
```

Comment: There are a [set of built in classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.formatter.serialization.odataserializer%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), but it isn't going to be pretty.

Comment: Those classes seem to be for the payload, not for uri. I am wrong?

Comment: probably not wrong. I more meant to show you a path to some of the documentation around the OData namespace... I don't believe that the serializer is A) simple and can be applied to any object, or 2) yet made public. Sorry.

Comment: [This may also help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525392%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With static class Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriUtils,
you can call ConvertToUriLiteral to serialize value to uri literal.

```
public static string ConvertToUriLiteral(object value, ODataVersion version)
public static string ConvertToUriLiteral(object value, ODataVersion version, IEdmModel model)
public static string ConvertToUriLiteral(object value, ODataVersion version, IEdmModel model, ODataFormat format)
```

And you can call ConvertFromUriLiteral to do deserialization.

```
public static object ConvertFromUriLiteral(string value, ODataVersion version)
public static object ConvertFromUriLiteral(string value, ODataVersion version, IEdmModel model, IEdmTypeReference typeReference)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my temporary implementation until someone knows the function in ODataLib.

```
static public string ToODataUriString(object value)
{
    if (value == null) return "null";
    switch (value.GetType().FullName)
    {
        case "System.Guid":
            return string.Format("guid'{0}'", (Guid)value);
        case "System.Decimal":
            return string.Format("{0}m", (decimal)value);
        case "System.Single":
            return string.Format("{0}f", ((Single)value).ToString("R"));
        case "System.Double":
            return string.Format("{0}d", ((double)value).ToString("R"));
        case "System.Boolean":
            return string.Format("{0}", (Boolean)value).ToLower();
        case "System.DateTime":
            {
                DateTime dvalue = (DateTime)value;
                string format;
                if (dvalue.Second==0 && dvalue.Millisecond==0)
                    format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"; //datetime’yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm[:ss[.fffffff]]’
                else if (dvalue.Millisecond == 0)
                    format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"; //datetime’yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm[:ss[.fffffff]]’
                else
                    format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff"; //datetime’yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm[:ss.fffffff]]’
                return string.Format("datetime'{0}'", dvalue.ToString(format));
            }
        case "System.DateTimeOffset":
            return string.Format("datetimeoffset'{0}Z'", ((DateTimeOffset)value).ToString("s"));
        case "System.Int16":
        case "System.Int32":
        case "System.Byte":
            return value.ToString();
        case "System.Int64":
            return string.Format("{0}L", value);
        case "System.TimeSpan":
            return string.Format("time'{0}'", (TimeSpan)value);
        case "System.String":
            // TODO Need better quote handling for escaping, this is not correct
            return string.Format("'{0}'", value.ToString().Replace("'", "''"));
        default:
            // TODO Need better quote handling for escaping, this is not correct
            return string.Format("'{0}'", value.ToString().Replace("'", "''"));
    }
}
```